# Unable to get property 'remove' of undefined or null reference (jquery-ui) with IE

Tags: asp.net, jquery-ui

I keep receiving this error in IE11 while trying to use .dialog() to display a license agreement. The jQuery UI is v1.11.4. I've attempted to switch to v1.12.1 and it doesn't seem to resolve this issue. The result is that the dialog displays only on Chrome and Edge.

SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'remove' of undefined or null reference
 jquery-ui.min.js (8,4523)

Code Sample:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("[id*=LicenseAgreementButton]").click(function () {
                    $("[id*=licenseDialog]").dialog({
                        dialogClass: "no-close",
                        modal: true,
                        draggable: false,
                        resizable: false,
                        minWidth: 600,
                        title: 'License Agreement',
                        buttons: {
                            'Accept': function () {
                                $("#LicenseAgreementContainer span input").prop("checked", true);
                                $(this).dialog('close');
                            }
                        }
                    })
                    $("[id*=licenseDialog]").dialog('open');
                })
            });
        </script>
 <div class="listComponents">
            <ul>
                <asp:ListView ID="ListDcdFiles" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="ListDcdFiles_OnItemDataBound">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <li>
                            <span><%# ((IDcdFileInfo)Container.DataItem).DcdFileTitle %></span>
                            <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnlLicenseAgreement" CssClass="clearfix">
                                <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hfDcdFileId"/>
                                <span class="dcdValidator"><TMA:TMACustomValidator runat="server" ID="vldCbAcceptAgreement" ShowInSummary="True" Enabled="True" ValidationGroup="ItemsList"
                                                    ErrorMessage="You must accept the license agreement in order to proceed" Text="*"
                                                    CssClass="validatedMessage" OnServerValidate="vldCbAcceptAgreement_OnServerValidate" /></span>
                                <div class="LicenseAgreementContainer" id="LicenseAgreementContainer">
                                    <asp:CheckBox ID="cbAcceptAgreement" runat="server" Checked="False" Text="Accept License Agreement" CssClass="cbAuthorize" />
                                    <div class="ViewLicenseAgreement">
                                        <input type="button" class="linkButton" ID="LicenseAgreementButton" value="View License Agreement"/>
                                    </div>
                                    <div  id="licenseDialog" style="display:none;">
                                        <div data-role="main" class="LicenseAgreementText">
                                            <asp:Literal runat="server" Mode="PassThrough" ID="htmlLicenseAgreement"></asp:Literal>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </asp:Panel>
                        </li>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:ListView>
            </ul>
       </div>
```

Comment: licenseDialog is within an item template of a list view. If you have more than one item, you will experience ID conflicts. try instantiating the Dialog using a class.

Comment: Thanks @Dimitri, that worked like a dream!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, thanks to a comment from @Dimitri I was able to resolve the issue. I just had to instantiate the Dialog using a class.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#LicenseAgreementButton").click(showDialog);

                $ldialog =  $("#licenseDialog");

                $ldialog.dialog({
                    dialogClass: "no-close",
                    autoOpen: false,
                    modal: true,
                    draggable: false,
                    resizable: false,
                    minWidth: 600,
                    title: 'License Agreement',
                    buttons: {
                        'Accept': function () {
                            $("#LicenseAgreementContainer span input").prop("checked", true);
                            $(this).dialog('close');
                        }
                    }
                });
            });

            var showDialog = function () {
                $ldialog.show();
                $ldialog.dialog("open");
            }
        </script>
```